# Create a report with the following structure: 1.(Page Header > Detail (two subreports as table) > Page Footer) 2.(Full page with a static text))

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to create a subreport with two pages, but the report must to follow of the subreports's size. Like this:

Page Header > Detail (two subreports as table) > Page Footer)

Full page with a static text

Page Header > Detail (two subreports as table) > Page Footer)

Full page with a static text

Page Header > Detail (two subreports as table) > Page Footer)

Full page with a static text

```
                           ... (n two pages)
```

I'm unable to create the second page with static text.

The two subreports behave as two tables coming from two different lists.

To limit subreports, I put the static fields of the report in the Page Header and Page Footer. It was a good practice?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **summary band** for 2'nd page.

```
<summary>
    <band height="800">
    ...your textfields
    </band>
</summary>
```

To make it always be in **new page** use

```
isSummaryNewPage="true"
```

To **avoid** `pageHeader` and  `pageFooter` use:

```
isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"
```

both on `jasperReport` tag